# Passing through solid objects

Tags: world-of-darkness, mage-the-ascension, mage-20th-anniversary

What Spheres are required to emulate Kitty Pride powers from X-Men (Marvel) or Flash ability to "vibrate through" from Justice League (DC)?

Context: my virtual adept is built to be a perfect spy and passing through walls will be next in his arsenal of invigilation abilities. Sadly, I can't find anything about this in rulebooks.

As usual: RAW answers only, from 20th Anniversary sources if possible, from earlier editions otherwise.

Comment: Are you the storyteller or a player?

Comment: Does it matter? It's a rules question.

Answer (score 4):

### Correspondence 3

Don't do anything to the wall, just rip open space on one side and on the other, connect the two and step through the wormhole. M20 p.513 & M20 HDYDT p.79: Gates and Portals

### Correspondence 3 + Matter 2

To change the wall's parameters so that it can be displaced, you can use correspondence, adding matter to affect the wall in the first place. The distance is about a foot, but the affected piece of wall is too large for Correspondence 2, so we need Correspondence 3, but staying at Matter 2 for the wall is simple. This follows directly from M20 p.513 and Correspondence 3 is outright called out on M20 HDYDT p.70.

On the other hand, Matter 2 outright calls out move
an object through space (Correspondence 2 or higher) in M20 p.518, so Matter 2 is perfect here, but sith the size requiring Correspondence 3, it would mean Matter 3 + Correspondence 3 ir Matter is the prime effect of the magic. This would by the way be the requirement to pass through reinforced concrete, because that is more complex and is not homogenous like a brick wall.

### Correspondence 3 + Life 3

To change your own properties so that your body can *slip between* the atoms of the wall, you can use Correspondence, adding life to affect yourself so that you don't suffer damage. Again we need Correspondence 3 for the size of the affected space, and due to your body being larger than a cat also Life 3. This likewise follows directly from M20 p.513 and M20 HDYDT p.70.

### Spirit 3

Just stop being physical and go through the spirit world for two steps. That falls under Step Sideways... twice... once to enter on one side and once to get back on the other. M20 p.521.

### Matter 5

Due to *insert reasons of your tradition* walls are not solid if you do *insert more traditionbabble*. You simply alter the properties of the wall to stop blocking you. It's vulgar but... you are master of matter. M20 p.520.

### Entropy 3

Why walk through the wall if you can just take the door? The bolt of the door didn't properly engage because it was too used when the guard locked it a minute ago and the camera just failed due to being old, and the padlock on the locker is of a bad type that allows to use a simple toothpick to press the latch away...

Oh, and that library card you showed the scanner totally recognizes as the ID to be there, if you also use Forces 2 in conjunction with it. That's all just affecting predictable patterns, but less going through the wall. No Paradox even! M20 p.515, M20 HDYDT p.73 & 75.

### Time 5

If you are a master of time, just shift yourself or the wall to a point where there is no obstacle, step forward, and shift back. But then again, that's how Cable would deal with walls, not Kitty. Oh, and remind to take your bag of paradox because reality hates this approach.

Comment: Problem is, p.70 in HDYDT talks about "step from one place to another" which is effectively teleportation. Same goes for p.513 in Core Rulebook. And Time 5 approach is a completely different thing. Time Travel to avoid obstacle is like shooting nuke to kill a fly. Is "increasing space between atoms so that object A can pass through object B" or something of similar nature mentioned anywhere directly? There's a major difference between teleportation and that... Way more possible utility in passing through things.

Comment: @NecXelos it's all about explaining stuff in your paradigm.

Comment: @NecXelos but there are more ways... just... half of them ignore the wall.

Comment: Problem is NOT "reaching other side of the wall" but "utilizing passing through in many creative ways, Kitty Pride abilities being the general concept". Hiding from explosion inside rock formation? Check. Imprisoning someone inside walls? Check. Spying from inside the wall? Check. Anything else I can't think of right now? Check.

Comment: Then you are left with matter 5